# WHOIS command on Ubuntu only returns a response code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, command-line-interface

I am attempting to lookup whois information programmatically utilizing python3 and the [whois command on Ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/whois.1.html).

For example:

```
import os

# Set domain
hostname = "google.com"
# Query whois
response = os.system("whois " + hostname)
# Check the response
print("This is the Response:" + str(response))
```

Returns this:

> ...MarkMonitor Domain Management(TM) Protecting companies and consumers
> in a digital world.
>
> Visit MarkMonitor at https://www.markmonitor.com Contact us at
> +1.8007459229 In Europe, at +44.02032062220
> -- **This is the Response:**0
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

The whois information is presented as expected (not seen in quote), however, the response is always just the exit code.

I require the information that precedes the exit code. I must search the whois information for specific fields. How do I approach this when response = 0?

**Solution:**

```
import subprocess

# Set domain
hostname = "google.com"
# Query whois
response = subprocess.check_output(
    "whois {hostname}".format(hostname=hostname),
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    shell=True)
# Check the response
print(response)
```

As pointed out below, [subprocess.check_output()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) should be used rather than os.system.

**Solution when looping:**

```
for domain in domain_list:
    hostname = domain
    response = subprocess.run(
        "whois {hostname}".format(hostname=hostname),
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        shell=True)
    # Check the response
    if response != 0:
        available.append(hostname)
    else:
        continue
```

[Subprocess.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) will continue the loop despite the != 0 response that occurs when a domain is unregistered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `subprocess.check_output` instead of `os.system`, see [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
exit_code = os.WEXITSTATUS(response)
```

or

```
return_value = os.popen("whois " + hostname).read()
```